# A routing error with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've this message when I try to create a new users.

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}
```

I don't understand why I've `:id=>nil`.

Here is the code :

UsersController.rb in controllers

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    @users = User.new
    @titre = 'Inscription'
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @users = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @users = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @users.save
        format.html { redirect_to @users, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @users, status: :created, location: @users }
      else
        @titre = "Inscription"
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

User.rb in models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessor :nom, :email
end
```

New.html.erb in views/users

```
<h1>Inscription</h1>

  <%= form_for(@users) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :nom %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :nom %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
      </div>
  <% end %>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

CreateUsers.rb in db/migrations

```
 class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|

      t.string :nom
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Thank you in advance for your answer.
Happy new year !

PS :

routes.rb

```
    users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
    edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
    PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
    DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

and _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@users) do |f| %>
  <% if @users.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@users.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @users.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How about posting your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: Can you also post your `form` partial, i.e. `<%= render 'form' %>`.

Comment: Are you sure that the @users object is not nil? User.find() will not throw any errors if the id is not found in the db

Comment: For Niels B. and Vee I've add `routes.rb` and `_form.html.erb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routes are defined in config/routes.rb, not in any of the code you posted.

You probably want a line like

```
resources :users
```

in your routes.rb file. That will provide routes for the seven default actions (index, show, new, create, edit, update, destroy).

Once you've defined an edit route for users, it'll direct requests for that route to the method you've defined in UsersController.

You'll also need to add a view at `views/users/edit.html.erb`. And probably get rid of that render line in your `new.html.erb` view -- that looks like you're trying to render a partial view, but that's not necessary since you have the form code directly in the view already.